# Как установить фокус веб-камеры в конкретное положение PC C++

Tags: c++, opencv, камера

Имеется проект Visual C++ с выводом изображения с использованием OpenCV, интересует как можно программно установить фокус в конкретное положение, естественно у камеры есть автофокус.

Заранее спасибо